# Using gRPC in User defined function in mysql (which is written in c++)

Tags: c++, mysql, grpc

I want to create a UDF in myql which when it is triggered should, a query should be sent to a gRPC server, My question is that how could I integrate gRPC client into UDF? my programming language is c++.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you make gRPC calls from your C++ client application, not from MySQL.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Thanks for response but I need to call it from UDF, as My app is based on MySql queries. I have to mention that UDF are written in c or c++. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What does the UDF do?

Comment: @Rick James as you know when we create a UDF (user defined function) in mysql, mysql loads a shared library where the c++ implementation of function is defined.

this library , it urn can be depend on another shared library with a gRPC client code, UDF supposed to connect as a gRPC client to a gRPC server. so UDF is a function that when I run the query select * from UDF_1 (assume the name of the UDF is UDF_1) it has to have a gRPC client library inside which can call a service from a gRPC server.

Comment: "from UDF_1" implies a "table".  But UDFs are "functions".

Comment: @Rick James this is the way we call functions in mysql.do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have sample SQL?

Comment: extern "C" char *hello(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
 char *result, unsigned long *length,
 char *is_null, char *error)
{
 
 strcpy(result, "Hello");
 strcat(result, " ");
 strcat(result, args->args[0]);
 *length=strlen(result);
  
 return result;
}

Comment: extern "C" bool hello_init (UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message)
{
 if(args->arg_count != 1)
 {
  strcpy(message, "hello requires exactly one string argument");
  return 1;
 }
 if(args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT)
 {
  strcpy(message, "hello requires exactly one string argument");
  return 1;
 }

 initid->max_length=args->lengths[0]+strlen("hello ");
 return 0; /* true */
}

Comment: extern "C" void hello_deinit (UDF_INIT *initid)
{
 return;
}

Comment: But what I want is to use gRPC client library into UDF and then when I call UDF, It calls the service to execute in gRPC server.

Comment: if you mean a UDF written in c++:as the number of characters in the comment in limited I will write in some comments you have to create a so file from it. using command gcc -shared -o UDF_TEST.so UDF_TEST.cc then copy .so file in your build dir. then you can: CREATE FUNCTION hello returns string SONAME 'UDF_TEST.so'; and then select UDF_TEST()